# Why does SWR in a loader not block the page load when caching with CDN compared to browser cache?

Tags: browser-cache, cache-control, remix.run

This is my loader and header functions:

```js
export async function loader() {
  const expenses = [
    {
      id: '637f853a8517a37d05c402b5',
      title: 'first expense',
      amount: 234,
    },
  ];

  // using this to slow down loader function to see if I am getting cache or not
  await new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(res, 5000);
  });

  console.log('loader is being called');

  return json(expenses, {
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=10, stale-while-revalidate=59',
    },
  });
}

export function headers({ loaderHeaders }) {
  return {
    'Cache-Control': loaderHeaders.get('Cache-Control'),
  };
}
```

`max-age` will correctly cache for 10 seconds, but when revalidation happens the loader gets called and the page won't load for 5 seconds (because of setTimeout). I assume I am still getting stale cache, but the page won't load until the loader is finished. So, this is not what I want when using `stale-while-revalidate`.

However, I get a different behavior when using a CDN to cache rather than the browser. Here is how I am using `s-maxage` for the CDN cache.

```js
  return json(expenses, {
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 's-maxage=1, stale-while-revalidate=59',
    },
  });
```

I am using Vercel to deploy this because of their CDN and `stale-while-revalidate` is working fine. It will revalidate in the background and give me stale cache for much quicker page loads. It does not seem to be effected by the setTimeout function. Why does this behave differently when using a CDN for the cache rather than the browser?

---

**What I Want**

SWR should give stale cache while it revalidates in the background and the page should load instantly (or at least quickly with CDN) regardless of browser or CDN cache.

**What Is Happening**

- When I use the browser to cache with `max-age` and `stale-while-revalidate`, `max-age` works fine and page load is instant for the specified duration. But, when revalidation occurs the setTimeout function in the loader prevents page load until it completes. I think this defeats the purpose of using SWR in a loader function when using browser cache (unless I am misunderstanding something).
- When I use the CDN to cache with `s-maxage` and `stale-while-revalidate`, `s-maxage` works correctly and page load is quick (not instant since it's coming from CDN) for that duration. Also, the setTimeout function in the loader does not prevent the page load. Instead, I get the stale cache and the page quickly loads without being blocked. This is exactly what I want and the reason I want to use SWR, but I want this with browser cache and I am interested to learn why this is not blocked by the loader function.

**What I Have Tried**

- I have tried different browsers on my MacBook and even an iPhone to see if caching with the browser would behave differently, but there was no difference between them.
- I have tried using fly, netlify, and vercel as deployment options to see if I notice any differences and they are all giving the same results. The same can be for said running this locally with `npm run dev`.
- I have tried starting a new Remix project.

Comment: Do your responses have `etag` or `last-modified` headers? They can interfere with SWR, so it's best to remove them if so. Also, a note on browser support: [only Chrome, Firefox, and Edge support SWR](https://caniuse.com/?search=stale-while-revalidate). You may want to include the time in the server-rendered response so you can ditch the timeout/delay for easier and more reliable testing.

Comment: @coreyward No, I am not using `etag` or `last-modified`. I have tried this on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. They all behave the same. I think I might understand why SWR in the loader function doesn't work with in-browser cache in my example. The browser is probably providing a cached response, but then it has to revalidate so the loader function will run again. I think this means the page cannot load until the loader is finished. Does this sound correct? Thanks for the suggestion to include server time.